# Weak convergence preserves pointwise limit inferior?

Tags: functional-analysis

Firstly, this forum has really helped me learn!

A question regarding whether weak convergence in $L^{2}$ preserves limits inferior. Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a finite measure space. Let $x_{n}\in L^{2}(\Omega,P)$ with $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly. Do we have $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n} = x$? Is there a simple proof?

My attempt was to try extracting sub-sequences of $x_{n}$ that converge almost everywhere to $x$, however, we know $x_{n}$ may not have a.e. convergent subsequences (sin(nx) for example).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no in general you do not preserve it. Weak converging sequences oscillate a lot so in general they do not have pointwise limit. The typical example is exactly $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$. If $x$ is irrational $\liminf_n \sin(nx)=-1$ but the sequence converges weakly to zero in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: $f_n\in L^2(0,1)$ since $|f_n(x)|\le 1$. You are in a finite measure space, not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: and one more question, why the sequence converges weakly to $0$?

Comment: it's a bit long to prove. First take $g=\chi_{(a,b)}$ and compute it directly making the change of variable $y=nx$ then take $g=\chi_{U}$ with $U$ open, the $g=\chi_{E}$ with $E$ measurable, then $g$ simple, then $g\in L^2$.

Comment: Let say $L^{2} (0, \pi)$ by scaling, then if your sequence is weakly convergent then we must have $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx) dx   \to 0$   is it right ?

Comment: yes, and more generally you need to show that $\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx)\,dx\to 0$ for every $g\in L^2((0,\pi))$. This is what I was trying to explain